# Intalled MySql but can't run it

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I have installed MySql Community Server `mysql-5.7.12-osx10.11-x86_64.pkg`. After the installation it gave me a root password as `root@localhost` with randomly generated password

```
2016-04-22T19:28:25.488115Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: r-SDM,<=6hir
```

Then i followed the documentation to run the MySQL from command line but got error that command not found

```
~/Documents/repos/ $: sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
Password:
sudo: /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM: command not found
```

I don't see mysqld running in mac activity monitor. Am i doing something wrong ? I followed the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is looking for the answer here is the solution

**Option 1**
Apple Icon on navbar > System Prefernces > At the bottom you would see `Mysql` icon - click on it > click on `Start MySql Server`

**Option 2** 
I haven't tested it yet

*to start*

`sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

*to stop*

`sudo launchctl unload -F  /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`